# Connecting ElephantSQL with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, urlparse

I'd like to connect ElephantSQL with Python.

```
import os
import psycopg2
import urlparse

urlparse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["MY_DATABASE_URL"])

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=url.path[1:],
  user=url.username,
  password=url.password,
  host=url.hostname,
  port=url.port
)
```

but i get error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 217, in 
>      url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["MY_DATABASE_URL"])
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in **getitem**
>      raise KeyError(key)
>   KeyError: 'MY_DATABASE_URL'

as my_database_url i write url from ElephantSQL (postgres://my_username:my_password@my_hostname/my_databasename)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That key does not exist in your environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='my_dbname' user='my_user' host='my_host' password='my_password'")
```

and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the ElephantSQL [documentation](https://www.elephantsql.com/docs/python.html) but the urllib.parse step did not work. I added the **psycopg2.connect** parameters directly as the solution above suggested following the ElephantSQL documentation syntax.

**postgres://username:password@hostname:port/database**

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="database", user="username", password="password", host="hostname", port="port")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
url = up.urlparse("DATABASE_URL")
```

instead of `url = up.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])` code that you found [ElephantSQL documentation](https://www.elephantsql.com/docs/python.html)

then I used

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=url.path[1:], user=url.username, password=url.password, host=url.hostname, port=url.port )
```

after that, I am able to connect elephantsql instance